# Multiple Image upload of single object ASP.NET MVC

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, razor

I am doing student college registration project. When student fills out admission form online he has to upload his previous transcripts in jpg, pdf , png.

i want that when latter admin will open that particular student details page, admin should view all this particular student details and the image of multiple uploaded files in the browser.

following is my viewModel class

```
public class ViewModel
{
    public int StudentID { get; set; }        //PK
    public string FirstName { get; set; }
    public string LastName { get; set; }
    public DateTime DateOfBirth { get; set; }
    public string Address { get; set; }
    public double PhoneNumber { get; set; }
    public string Email { get; set; }
    public DateTime AppliedDate { get; set; }
    public byte[] Picture { get; set; }
    public int AppliedID { get; set; }      
    public int CourseID { get; set; }       
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure if I fully understand your question but it sounds like you need to change the data structure of the uploaded files in your student model. If you're having trouble with passing a collection in a model to a view, you need to iterate over each of them. For instance:

Student:

```
public IEnumerable<string> UploadedFile;
```

View:

```
@foreach (var file in Model.UploadedFiles)
{
    // display
}
```

Comment: i am basically trying to upload multiple files of students maybe in pdf or image files. and when admin wants to see that particular student details he can see file images on the browser with other deatils of that particular student.  Please guide to solve this problem.

Comment: can you update your original question with your code so far so that I can better understand your question

Comment: @mudassirsheikh - your Picture property only has one byte array, if this is being used by multiple uploads, then it will not be correctly displayed. Either make it a collection, or add more properties